# Calculate big-O with a table of execution-times?

Tags: big-o, execution-time

Lets say i have a table of bitsize and executiontime, where bitsize is the size of the number i feed into the algorithm.

```
 bitsize   -  exectime

 512       -    5
 1024      -    50
 2048      -    500
```

What does it mean to calculate big-O as a function of bitsize? and how would I do it for this case?

I can see that the time increases as 0.5 * 10^x

If I wanted to figure out what the next executiontime would be I could also do this:

(50/1024)/(5/512) = 5

(500/2048)/(50/1024) = 5

(t/4096)/(500/2048) = 5 => t = 5000

Comment: You don't "calculate O(n)"; that doesn't make any sense. However, the table shows an algorithm of time complexity *O(n)* where n is the length of the input/the size of the number in bits.

Comment: "time increases as 0.5 * 10^x" that is probably a misconception. What should x be?

Comment: well i dont really understand the big O notation but the time increases exponentially? when bitsize doubles, time increases 10-fold, I thought O(n) was linear growth?

Comment: woops meant to write big-O not O(n) in the question

Comment: Yeah, I think you're about right: 10^x/2^x

Answer (score 0):

The data in this table suggests that when you double the size of the input, the runtime of the function grows by a factor of ten. So it's reasonable to guess that the runtime is O(f(n)), where f(n) is some function with the above behavior and n is the bit size. The question is how to find a function like this.

A reasonable guess here is that you're looking at some flavor of polynomial, since generally speaking if you double the size of the input to a polynomial function, the output grows by some constant fraction. So let's suppose that f(n) = n<sup>k</sup> for some constant k. We'd like to pick k so that f(2n) = 10f(n). That means that we'd solve

> (2n)<sup>k</sup> = 10n<sup>k</sup>
>
> 2<sup>k</sup>n<sup>k</sup> = 10n<sup>k</sup>
>
> 2<sup>k</sup> = 10
>
> k = log<sub>2</sub> 10

So a reasonable guess here is that the runtime is O(n<sup>log<sub>2</sub> 10</sup>). This isn't necessarily the case because the runtime might change in different ways for larger and larger inputs, but it's still a reasonable guess to make.

If you'd like to extrapolate out from here, you'd need to work out the constant factors hidden in the big-O notation. Try seeing if you can fit something of the form cn<sup>log<sub>2</sub> 10</sup> to the data points. Once you've got it, the extrapolation should give you a reasonable guess for future inputs.